# Express handlebars wont render data

Tags: express, express-handlebars

Hey guys so I have the following in my app.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const hbs = require("express-handlebars");

    app.engine(
      "hbs",
      hbs({
        extname: "hbs",
        //defaultLayout: "layout",
        layoutsDir: __dirname + "/views/layouts/"
      })
    );
    app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
    app.set("view engine", "hbs");
```

I also have a file located in server/views/layouts/ that is a handle bars file called share.hbs
I also have a file in my server/api/media.js that looks like this

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const database = require("../db");
router.get("/share", async (req, res, next) => {
  res.render("share");
});
```

But when ever I try to render the file it errors out with the following error

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is an error logged in your console? If so, could you share it?

Comment: I am reading the express-handlebars documentation. Shouldn't `share.hbs` be located in the `views` directory? https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars

Comment: I even moved the file out of layouts into views and it cannot find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to move my file out of the layouts folder and add this to the res.render call

```
  res.render("share.hbs", { layout: "share" });
```

Comment: Where did you move the `share.hbs` file to?

Comment: views directory and deleted layout

Comment: In that case, if you found (one of )my comments useful, please upvote them.